# End session window on seeing an end signal

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm exploring Kafka Streams for a sessionization use case and wanted to understand if there is a way to end a session window earlier than the inactivity gap if it sees an end signal earlier ?
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm exploring Kafka Streams for a sessionization use case and wanted to understand if there is a way to end a session window earlier than the inactivity gap if it sees an end signal earlier ?

No, this is not possible out of the box.  The session window implementation in KStreams uses inactivity as the sole parameter to determine whether a window (session) should or should not be closed.

If you need a different behavior you can use the Processor API of Kafka Streams.  For example, I have seen developers that implement custom 'sessions' based on finite state machines.  For example, reconstructing a TCP/IP session from raw network data can be done in this way.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that.